# Invoke namespaced rake task in ruby code

Tags: ruby, rake

Given some ruby file `foo.rb`:

```
require 'rake'

namespace :tmp do
  desc "Foo bar baz.."
  task :some_task do
    puts "running some task..."
  end
end
```

How can I invoke the namespaced task `tmp:some_task` task in ruby?

I've tried:

```
require_relative 'foo'
#=> true
Rake::Task[tmp:some_task].invoke
#=> NameError: undefined local variable or method `some_task' for main:Object
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling the task incorrectly - pass the name of the task as string:

```
Rake::Task['tmp:some_task'].invoke
```

Answer (score 0):

The Accepted answer is correct. But, from rails, to invoke any rake task from Rails. you  need to load them first.

```
require 'rake'
Rails.application.load_tasks
Rake::Task['my_task'].invoke
```